# Calculate mean of data by year

Tags: matlab

[image]

I've got data of several years from 1958 to 2016. I want to plot the annual average vs year. Is there an easier way to do it than what I've done?

```
%Want to make an array of annual averages
avg = [];

for n = 1958:2016

    sum = 0;
    year_counter = 0;

    %there are 708 observations
    for k = 1:708

        %if the year matches, look up the corresponding value and add it to the sum
        if data(k, 1) == n
            sum = sum + data(k,2);
            year_counter = year_counter + 1;
        end

    end

    %append the average to the array
    avg = [avg s/year_counter];

end
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html

Comment: @Daniel Thanks! just what I need